# Unable to install libxml2 and lxml on pypy - python 2.7

Tags: python, xml, xslt, lxml, libxml2

I know there were many, many questions asked about installing lxml but I could not find anything that solves my problem. If I missed an answer, please refer me to it.
I'll try to give you as much as information as I can think of.

So I'm trying to install [lxml](http://lxml.de/installation.html) .

I run on windows 10, platform.uname() output is:

```
import platform
platform.uname()
('Windows', 'DESKTOP-6AH7RBF', '10', '10.0.15063', 'AMD64', 'Intel64 Family 6 Model 142 Stepping 9, GenuineIntel')
```

And my interpreter is pypy:

```
import sys
sys.version
'2.7.13 (14f400f0498e, Mar 31 2017, 19:58:36)\n[PyPy 5.7.1 with MSC v.1500 32 bit]'
```

setuptools version is 36.2.7

When ran the pip command, got this output:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>c:\pypy27\bin\pip.exe install c:\Users\Jack\Downloads\lxml-cffi.zip
Processing c:\users\jack\downloads\lxml-cffi.zip
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Building lxml version 3.4.0.
    Building without Cython.
    ERROR: 'xslt-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.

    ** make sure the development packages of libxml2 and libxslt are installed **

    Using build configuration of libxslt _cffi__gf1d3c271xb1c86544.c
    src\lxml-cffi\includes\__pycache__\_cffi__gf1d3c271xb1c86544.c(53) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'libxml/chvalid.h': No such file or directory

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<module>", line 1, in <module>
      File "c:\users\jack\appdata\local\temp\pip-twwxp3-build\setup.py", line 232, in <module>
        **setup_extra_options()
      File "c:\users\jack\appdata\local\temp\pip-twwxp3-build\setup.py", line 145, in setup_extra_options
        STATIC_CFLAGS, STATIC_BINARIES)
      File "setupinfo.py", line 167, in ext_modules
        import lxml.etree
      File "src\lxml\../lxml-cffi\etree.py", line 8, in <module>
        from .apihelpers import _assertValidNode, _assertValidDoc
      File "src\lxml\../lxml-cffi\apihelpers.py", line 3, in <module>
        from .includes.etree_defs import _isString, _getNs, _isElement
      File "src\lxml\includes\../../lxml-cffi/includes\etree_defs.py", line 1, in <module>
        from . import tree
      File "src\lxml\includes\../../lxml-cffi/includes\tree.py", line 498, in <module>
        libraries=['xml2'])
      File "C:\pypy27\lib_pypy\cffi\api.py", line 438, in verify
        lib = self.verifier.load_library()
      File "C:\pypy27\lib_pypy\cffi\verifier.py", line 114, in load_library
        self._compile_module()
      File "C:\pypy27\lib_pypy\cffi\verifier.py", line 211, in _compile_module
        outputfilename = ffiplatform.compile(tmpdir, self.get_extension())
      File "C:\pypy27\lib_pypy\cffi\ffiplatform.py", line 20, in compile
        outputfilename = _build(tmpdir, ext, compiler_verbose, debug)
      File "C:\pypy27\lib_pypy\cffi\ffiplatform.py", line 56, in _build
        raise VerificationError('%s: %s' % (e.__class__.__name__, e))
    VerificationError: CompileError: command 'C:\\Users\\Jack\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microsoft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\jack\appdata\local\temp\pip-twwxp3-build\
```

As the error and the lxml docs say, I need to install first [libxml2](http://xmlsoft.org/) and [libxslt](http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/) . So I entered the download [page of libxml2](ftp://xmlsoft.org/libxml2/) and downloaded the latest version - 2.9.4

And ran pip install on the downloaded tar.gz:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>c:\pypy27\bin\pip.exe install c:\Users\Jack\Downloads\libxml2-2.9.4.tar.gz
Processing c:\users\jack\downloads\libxml2-2.9.4.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<module>", line 1, in <module>
    IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\\users\\jack\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-4ww1fs-build\\setup.py'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\jack\appdata\local\temp\pip-4ww1fs-build\
```

Did the same for versions 2.9.3 and 2.9.2 and got similar results.

What am I missing? How can I fix it so I can install lxml?

Thanks in advance for all of those involved!

Comment: have you installed setuptools?

Comment: Yes, version: 36.2.7